# opencl runtime error in loop ( Clenqueuewritebuffer )

Tags: c, for-loop, opencl, runtime-error

When I use OpenCL to process many chunks of data it crashes in the 7th iteration.
I ensure that memory is released before each iteration of the loop, and allocated again for new chunk, but the crash still occurs with an error of **-38** on **Clenqueuewritebuffer()**

I have tried a lot, but am not getting anywhere.

The following is the flow of my code :

```
    clGetPlatformIDs
    clGetDeviceIDs
    clCreateContext
    clCreateCommandQueue
    clCreateProgramWithSource
    clBuildProgram
    clCreateKernel

    for(x){
            clCreateBuffer
            clEnqueueWriteBuffer
            clSetKernelArg
            clEnqueueNDRangeKernel
            clFinish
            clEnqueueMapBuffer
            clReleaseMemObject
          }
```

Is it correct or do I have to use it in other ways?
If so, What am I doing wrong?...

Comment: please show us some code (www.sscce.org)

Comment: please show real code, `for(x)` can't be valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some code and the specific command where this error comes up would be nice.

Error -38 is `CL_INVALID_MEM_OBJECT`
Please check if you initialised all memory object correctly.

Could you explicitly check for the output of `clCreateBuffer` `clCreateImage..` whatever you are using? This error could also come if the Buffer you provided to your kernel doesn't match it's parameter definition in terms of type or read/write modifiers.

---

EDIT to match the edited question:

1) You can change the kernel arg when the kernel is not running, but good practice is to set a kernel arg only once. (At best directly after clCreateKernel) 
Even better is to reuse the assigned buffer. (Or create several kernels if you use the same buffer combinations several times)
In your case I would at least do `createBuffer and setKernelArg` before the loop and `releaseMemObject` after the loop.

2) You are doing `clEnqueueMapBuffer` on you mem-object. This should be followed by a `clEnqueueUnmapMemObject` when you are done interacting with you object. If you just want to read data from your buffer, try: `enqueueReadBuffer` as equivalent to `enqueueWriteBuffer`

Comment: i use gdebuger output was correct !! point of crash change frequently

Comment: problem was memory leak, but your instruction was helpful.